# Installing CentOS on HP Server, SSDs connected to a RAID controller

Tags: raid, centos6, hp-proliant, drivers, dd

I am trying to install centOS 6.0 in this
[HP Server](http://www8.hp.com/es/es/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=7183206), I contacted with the support and they said me that it supports that OS.

I have no problem installing it on a SSD that is connected directly to the motherboard, but if I connect it to the raid controller H240 the install says that there are not storage devices to install it.

Even using the HP Intelligent Provisioning, and configuring the raid through the Smart Storage Administrator I don't see any disk when I am going to install. I don't see them anyway if I break the array and I clear the config.

I know I can add the drivers of the controller to the install pressing tab on the boot menu of the DVD, adding "linux dd blacklist=ahci". Then it questions me if I have got any driver cd/dvd/usb, the format of the drivers must be  " .dd " or it says: error loading the controller from the file.

I know there are some threads about this kind of question, but my main problem is I can't find the drivers in dd format.

The [HP web page](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=7481832&swLangOid=35&swEnvOid=4103) only offers me " .rpm " packets (for red hat 6, CentOS is supported but is not in the drop down menu for choosing it *btw this is anoying because the suport says it is officially supported*).

I tried to install centOS in the disk connected directly to the motherboard, install that rpm, power off. Then I connected the disk to the raid controller and power on again. But I can't boot from disk anyway.

Can I convert rpm to dd? Where can I find the drivers in the dd format?

Is there any other form to install CentOS 6.0 in the SSD with the disks connected to the raid controller that I forgot?

Thanks.

Edit: SOLVED

In the HP matrix web page you can check the minimal supported system which is centos 6.5.

That is because the smart hba h240 controller modifies the basic model.

I will negotiate about test this version in the company and install it with the dd drivers that they provided me.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is newer than the OS you're installing. Use the newest release of CentOS, and you'll have the appropriate drivers necessary to install the operating system and recognize the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I editted the post saying that is solved :D

Comment: That's good. But the advice is the same.